# Spring boot microservices

Tags: spring-boot

In a java Spring boot web app a microservice has three different  entities  with their corresponding controllers, repository and service layers. How do I join these entities to come up with one complete entity that can communicate independently and be accessed remotely by the existing different corresponding service, controller and repository layers without creating new combined repo, service and controller.

Expected one to create one entity that could be accessed remotely but different services